# Are there any CMS add ons for SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, page-layout, publishing-page

We recently rolled out a new site where we are allowing users to create their own public facing page content.  Shortly after we gave them access it became clear that the majority of the content that is going up is hideous.  Entire pages that are centered and bolded, pages with a six character link on it, etc.

We were able to lock down the formatting and only give them a few pre-defined styles that they can use, but most of the pages are still pretty gross.

I was wondering if anyone has heard of an add on for SharePoint that will allow you to provide several pre-defined layouts for the Page Content section of page?  Something that allows them to enter text in a specific area, insert an image in a specific area, but all of the styling is specific to what area they type into.

Just to be clear, the Page Content section is already a column in a custom page layout that I have created.

Attempt at an example for a template I would like within my Page Content section:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the page layouts feature that is part of the SharePoint Web Content Management workload.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573556.aspx

Comment: Well the Page Content section is a column within a Page Layout that I am using.  I just want this specific column to have templates for how users can enter data.  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Well that the problem. Your content type should have multiple columns: One for header section, one for image, one for main content, one for teaser, one for rollup image, one for rollup text, .... Very often I'll disable HTML in these or at least limit it. And then you should have multiple pagelayouts each of then defining how to present all (or some) of the columns.

Comment: I had considered that, but it adds signification complexity in other portions of my application if I can't just have one page layout and know that all the content I care about is in the Page Content column.  It sounds like you are saying that there is nothing you know of that will allow me to do the above entirely in one Page Content column?

Comment: @Abe - Not sure what is wrong with Paul's response as the Page Layout capability in ShareoPoint Publishing sites gives you exactly what you're looking to do: multiple rendering options for a single type of a page. You're asking for CMS add ons but there's one right in front of you in the box.